# Angularjs - factory not working in an external file

Tags: angularjs

So this issue only seems to happen when I move a factory to an external file, and I'm really confused as to why. Extracting directives, controllers, and filters to external files does not break my app. I'll show what I'm doing below.

I create my app.js, name the module, inject my various dependencies, continue with my config, and create my factory.

```
---- app.js -----

angular
  .module('myApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',])
  .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) { ... })
  .factory('myFactory', function($http){ ... });
  // also works with .factory('myFactory', ['$http', function($http) { ... }]);
```

I have no issue accessing my factory in my controller this way.

```
---- controller.js ------

angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('myController', function(myFactory){
    myFactory.method() // works just fine
  });
```

Alternatively :

```
---- controller.js ------

angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('myController', [ 'myFactory', function(myFactory){
    myFactory.method() // also works just fine
  }]);
```

Not sure which syntax is "right" but I try both always and they both work just fine.

...Now, if i remove .factory from app.js and move it to myFactory.js (which is linked in index.html) is where the problem happens.

```
----- myFactory.js -----
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('myFactory', function($http) { ... }); // also attempted with [ ] syntax
```

The app now fails to load after refresh, and I receive a pnpr error.

I've attempted:

- Removing $http from the factory, and also leaving the factory empty to ensure I wasn't returning bad code from within the factory.
- Changing myFactory.js's angular.module to read

  ```
  angular.module('myFactory', []);
  angular.module('myFactory').factory('api', [ '$http', function($http){ ... });
  ```

then in app.js injecting 'myFactory' as a dependency... I get some different error all together:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module crema.app due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myFactory due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myFactory' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument. [errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/nomod?p0=myFactory](https://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/nomod?p0=myFactory)

- Loading myFactory.js 1st, 2nd, 9th, last... in index.html, thinking maybe the load order might matter? It did not.
- And various other minor syntactical changes. Nothing seems to really help, or change my error.

Not really sure what else to try. Like I said, the factory functions as intended when inside of app.js, and all my controllers, directives, etc. work just fine in external files... just not this factory. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend you go with your second dot-point and post the error in your question. Saying you get error messages and not adding them to your question doesn't help anybody

Comment: The error in point 2 is 'Error: $injector:modulerr'. Failed to instantiate module due to [$injector:nomod]. following up on this error tells me to double check spellings and check if the module is loaded. I've done both. same error happens again.

Comment: That's about half the **actual error message**. Seriously, do you want help or not? I'd also recommend you use the unminified version of Angular and any other libraries while you're developing; the error messages are more verbose.

Comment: My apologies. The full error returned, after switching to to the unminified version of angular is: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module crema.app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myFactory due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myFactory' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/nomod?p0=myFactory
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP ... many /bower_components/ urls after

Comment: I'm also using the approach in bullet 2 now angular.module('myFactory', []);
angular.module('myFactory').factory('api', [
    '$http',
    function($http){ ... });

Comment: Add it all to your question, comments are not the right place for code and error messages. Also show your modified `app.js` file. As it stands, you should have a module dependency for `myFactory` and inject `api` into your controller

Comment: Readdressed this problem today... I run my Angular app on top of a Nodejs server. Well I tried running my Angular app on top of python SimpleHTTPServer today, and the factory worked in an external file, without issue. I can only assume there is an issue with Nodejs and there never was an issue with my Angular implementation.

Comment: Sounds like your problem is more of a routing problem with NodeJS. I use the static server and it works good if you put all your files under public. app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that AngularJS does not allow you to register factories after its bootstrap. In order to make it work, you should do the following in your config function:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [...]);
app.config(function($provide) {
    app.factory = function(name, factory) {
        $provide.factory(name, factory);
    };
});
```